# Maven resource filtering not working - because of spring boot dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

In a maven project I trying to replace some tokens using maven resource filtering but it does not work. I have some other projects which works but does not work in this single project not sure what is wrong.

The property files is in location /src/main/resources/my.properties

I tried different maven commands as below but does not work.

```
mvn clean install
mvn clean install resources:resources
```

**my.properties**

```
### Spring boot properties
jdbc.url=${jdbc.url}
ldap.domain=${ldap_domain}
ldap.url=${ldap_url}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jai</groupId>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>client</name>
    <description>client web application</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>client</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-bower-install</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>bower</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


    <profiles>
        <!-- localhost environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>

            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <properties>

                <ldap_domain>mydomain.local</ldap_domain>
                <ldap_url>ldap://server:389</ldap_url>
                <jdbc.url>testttttttttttttttttttttt</jdbc.url>

            </properties>
        </profile>

        </profiles>

</project>
```

**Update:-**

I figured out this problem is caused due to the spring boot dependency.
If I comment the `<parent>` section and other spring boot dependencies, then it works fine and able to replace the token. But still not sure how to fix this by keeping spring boot.

Comment: Seems this is a defect in spring boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/980

Comment: still an issue with spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 302, accepted):

At last found the answer from the link in my comments. As this is a spring boot application ...special case... the notations should be

```
@xxxxx@  instead of ${xxxxx}
```

So my property file would be as below

```
### Spring boot properties
jdbc.url=@jdbc.url@
ldap.domain=@ldap_domain@
ldap.url=@ldap_url@
```

Comment: You have more information about that in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: Just to keep people from hunting, this was changed in SB 1.3.0.  Here are the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#maven-resources-filtering

Comment: I'm using @ but still not working. I'm trying to inject a property during the build.

mvn clean install -DsecretProperty=hello

and have a property in my property file value.from.file=@secretProperties@

what I got when I run my Spring boot application is this -> @secretProperties@

Comment: I can'be belive this is still an issue in Spring Boot 2.5.4. But it is.