# How to get log4j2.properties file to read filename from pom.xml in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I been searching internet and i might have missed. But what i am trying to achieve in my code is, have a log4j2.properties file read file names defined in pom.xml in a Spring boot project. Something like below.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
 <log.file>/expo/net/logs/xol/aws.log</log.file>
 <status.file>/export/net/logs/xol/tdlg.log</status.file>
</properties>
```

log4j2.properties:

```
appender.main.type=RollingFile
appender.main.name=MAIN
#appender.main.fileName=${log.file}
appender.main.filePattern=${log.file}.%d{yyyyMMddHH}
appender.main.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.main.layout.pattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p  %highlight{%t}  %replace{%msg}{\n\r|\n|\r}{ }%n
appender.main.policies.type=Policies
appender.main.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.main.policies.time.interval=1
appender.main.policies.time.modulate=true
```

My expectation is when run the maven correct values should get replaced in.
Any suggestions where i am going wrong?

Comment: May be this link will help you :- http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html

Comment: I think the best thing might be to use filtering...

Comment: I did try filtering, but doesn't seem to work. I think somehow parent thing messing up everything.

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> 
 </parent>

Comment: Make sure that `log4j2.properties` is placed within `resources` folder. Otherwise it should be explicitly provided to maven-resources-plugin  to be filtered

Comment: It is in resources folder. But the way Spring-Boot works is different i feel.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution. Someone had asked similar question.

[Maven resource filtering not working - because of spring boot dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501017/maven-resource-filtering-not-working-because-of-spring-boot-dependency)

It is explained on below link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

In my log4j2.properties file i replaced "${" and "}" with "@".

```
appender.main.type=RollingFile
appender.main.name=MAIN
#appender.main.fileName=@log.file@
appender.main.filePattern=@log.file@.%d{yyyyMMddHH}
appender.main.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.main.layout.pattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p  %highlight{%t}  %replace{%msg}{\n\r|\n|\r}{ }%n
appender.main.policies.type=Policies
appender.main.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.main.policies.time.interval=1
appender.main.policies.time.modulate=true
```

Worked like a charm. Thanks guys for all the inputs.