# Using pom.xml SystemProperty in log4j2 configuration file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

There is a property in my pom.xml that I'd like to use in log4j2.xml. However log4j2 seems to not detect that property and the file cannot be created.

The property is defined in a following way:

```
<systemProperty>
    <name>log.location</name> 
    <value>${project.build.directory}/logs</value>
</systemProperty>
```

And that how I refer to that in a log4j2.xml:

```
fileName="${sys:log.location}"
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813686/how-to-get-log4j2-properties-file-to-read-filename-from-pom-xml-in-spring-boot use @xxxxx@ instead of ${xxxxx} it will work.

Comment: It just creates a directory with that name and doesn't use a system property.

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j2.xml file Use 
`<property name="fileName">${filename}</property>` // this will fatch your filename from pom.xml

than use "${fileName}" wherever you want to use in your log4j2. this way it will work.